# Delete consecutive same characters in a sequence using stack

Tags: data-structures, stack

> Delete consecutive same characters in a sequence using stack. Ask the user to enter a series of characters until the user enters ‘F’ or ‘f’. Now the task is to check if any two similar characters come together then they destroy each other. Print the new sequence after this pairwise destruction.
>
> Pseudo code
>
> ```
> n = input ()
>
> if stack is empty {
>   push n 
> }
>
> else  {
>   m = pop from stack
>   
>   if m != n {
>      push m
>      push n
>    }
> }
> ```

Can this pseudo code work? I want to implement it without using sets, hashmaps, vectors, etc.

Comment: What makes you think the pseudo code doesn't work?  It looks fine to me.  Did you try to actually implement it yet? Are you having a particular problem with that?

Comment: I would probably change the logic a little, though. Rather than unconditionally popping the top element and then pushing it back in, I would *peek* the top element first, and if it matches the user's input then I would pop the top element, otherwise push the input, eg: `m = peek top from stack; if m == n { pop top from stack } else { push n }`